# Overriding UseAuthorization behaviour in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

In the asp.net core application,  I want to write Authorization middleware on my own . I am trying to implement it similar to Example 2.
But if I try to use I get compilation error saying "**IApplicationbuilder doesnt contain a definition of UseAuthorization**"

How to add my custom method to IApplicationBuilder?In which file I need to add my method?.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,IHostingenvironment env)
{
 app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseAuthorization(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
 return app.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: Chances are that you are missing a using statement for the correct namespace in `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 0):

Go the definition of your `UseAuthorization` to check whether you install sdk of Asp.Net Core.

[image]

If not, you could install and rebuild again.

[Downloads for .NET Framework and .NET Core, including ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)